# What are the conditions for an object to be "invisible"?

Tags: optics, everyday-life, geometric-optics

So, I came across [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bFNpxzwng0Q) which shows a couple of men doing push-ups, seemingly without using their arms.

My question is, what could be a logical explanation?

Theorising in the comments:

1. The FORCE
2. Incredibly strong legs and abdomen
3. An invisible rope
4. Green screen

Needless to say, I rejected the first two possibilities (hehehe). **So, if it's an invisible rope, what exactly is the condition for the rope to be invisible?**

1. Coefficient of transmission = 1
2. Or, refractive index = 1 (ie, equal to that of air)

The second possibility came to mind when I watched a video where an object having  refractive index equal to that of water became very hard to see when underwater; I can't understand why, though.

The video is really puzzling me, and an explanation would be nice. Thanks :)

Comment: May a green rope...

Comment: Would [skeptics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: 5. Clever video editing, possibly compositing camera-acquired images with CGI.

Comment: Saw a similar video.. there's a plank beneath the man.. kind of like a see saw.

Comment: P.S., In big-budget movie special effects, when they need to hide the rope from which some actor or prop is dangling, they airbrush it out, frame-by-frame.  They've been doing that since back in the day when editors worked with scissors and sticky tape.

Comment: @jameslarge did you watch the video? Quite a potato-quality vid, doubt anything sophisticated like cgi was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object is "invisible" if all light rays traveling from behind the object to the viewer's eye are undeflected.  In other words, they travel from the background to your eye exactly the same way when the object is present and when the object is absent.

This means that there can be no absorption of the light rays, and that if any light rays are deflected by the object, the object must also "return them" to their original paths.  Otherwise, you'd be able to tell that a light ray from the background had been deflected (or was "missing"), which would allow you to detect the object.  For an object made of a single material, with a single index of refraction, this turns out to imply that the object must have the same index of refraction as the medium the rays are traveling through.  In other words, you must have *both* no absorption and no refraction for such an object to be "invisible".

However, it is possible to (effectively) vary the index of refraction in various locations in the object to "guide" the light around an object;  this is the science behind [metamaterial cloaking.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamaterial_cloaking)  So far, this has only been achieved for microwave frequencies (rather than for visible light), but physicists are continuing to work in this field and see whether they can extend it into the visible range.

Comment: That explains the invisibility part very well. :)